# Create a row in another table based on currently inserted row

Tags: mysql, database, insert

I think that there was a way that by not making two `INSERT` statements we could add a row on another table. I don't know if it was about `CASCADE`ing or not but didn't find anything based on the keywords (*wrong maybe!*) I used.

Currently I've two tables, one is `users` and the other is `data`, when a user is created I want a row in `data` table get added so in this way I can update it later. `data` columns are all nullable except the `uid` which is user id on `data` table -*Unique*- that respectfully lives in `id` column of `users` table.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if the user adds data, check if the row exists and if not, insert it with the `uid` = `user id` ? If that user is not adding data, then you have an empty row in your db ...

Comment: @KarelG yes that's the first thing comes in mind but I don't like the messy things until something better is not out there.

Comment: Why not use a trigger on `users`?

Comment: I hope [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) helps

Comment: JPA would do that if you were using some sort of hierarchy I guess, but I think behind the scenes, it's two INSERTs anyway :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the guys that triggered me to use a `TRIGGER`. I wasn't familiar with them at all!
Here is the Trigger, as simple as possible, for the later visitors of this topic:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    TRIGGER `user_after_insert` AFTER INSERT 
    ON `users` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO data (uid) VALUES (NEW.id);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I don't recommend reading docs if you're a newbie in them like me but [**this page**](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-triggers/) that will help you unserstand more with some examples!